# Как считать отмеченную роль в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, role

Я планирую сделать команду `!addrole @тест @<role>`, но пока только вышло так: `!addrole @тест <role>`.

Мне надо чтобы бот считывал `@<role>` отмеченную в команде.

Код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member: ds.Member, role):
  dob_role = ds.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name=role)
  await member.add_roles(dob_role)
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} тебе была назначена роль {dob_role.mention}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member: ds.Member, role: ds.Role):
  await member.add_roles(role)
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} тебе была назначена роль {role.mention}')
```